# Shopify Admin Api /checkouts - "errors": "Not found"

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am trying  to complete a payment through the shopify admin api.  I made a request to the card vault (https://elb.deposit.shopifycs.com/sessions) and got the `session_id`, but when I try to make this call, I keep getting  "Not Found".  I have checked the access to the private app and it seems to have the right permissions.  I'm not sure what else to try - I've combed through all the Shopify documentation to no avail. TIA!

[image]

Comment: Do you passed correct token value instead `xxxxxx` ?

Comment: yes -  I think so, which token value should it be to make sure I'm doing it correctly?

Comment: from response  `/admin/api/2021-04/checkouts.json` field `token`